# Side by side Scatter plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to build a plot that compares two groups in four different categories, side by side, all with the same y scale (example data below). I have tried to use the `group_by` function to group data prior to plotting however I only get data for both groups combined in all categories (shown in image). I do not want to facet the plots, although if there is no other option, this may have to work. I feel this should be a simple answer, but if anyone could help with where I am going wrong, I would be very appreciative.

Example data:

```
    Group Category yvar        
    1     cat1     76.41383        
    1     cat2     51.24885
    1     cat3     68.20408
    1     cat4     79.14243
    2     cat1     72.35527
    2     cat2     64.61710
    2     cat3     75.75096
    2     cat4     73.71880
```

Script used:

```
my_data %>%
 group_by(Group) %>%
 ggplot(aes(x = Category, y = yvar)) +
 geom_jitter(width = 0.1) +
 geom_boxplot(alpha = 0)
```

Plot example
[image]

Comment: Add `aes(color  = Group)` to `geom_jitter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an approach with `stat_boxplot` and `geom_dotplot`:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = as.factor(Category), y = yvar, fill = as.factor(Group))) +
   stat_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA, alpha = 0) +
   geom_dotplot(binaxis = "y", 
                stackdir = "center",
                position = position_dodge(0.75),
                dotsize = 0.7, binwidth = 0.5) + 
   scale_fill_manual(values = c("firebrick3","cornflowerblue")) +
   labs(fill = "Group", y = "Y Variable", x = "Category")
```

[image]

**Data**

```
set.seed(3)
data <- data.frame(Group = rep(1:2,each = 80),
                    Category = rep(LETTERS[1:4], each = 20),
                    yvar = do.call(c,lapply(1:8,function(x){rnorm(20,x,2)})))
```

Comment: Thanks Ian, if anything it needs to be opposite with box plots for each group, rather than overall. Ideally, I am looking to overlay box plots over each groups scatter data

Comment: I don't understand, you just want to recreate the plot in your question?

Comment: Apologies, within the plot in the question, both group's data is plotted together. What I would like to be able to do is separate each group's data so they sit side by side, rather than combined. Essentially then, there would be 8 'sets' of scatter data with box plot overlayed. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: Thats great Ian. Exactly what I am looking for! I will run this with my data as soon as possible and set it as answered. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What if you added `fill` or `color` to `aes()` and assigned the `Group` variable to one of them? That should give you the same plot as the one above, but now with one set of four box plots in one color representing `Group 1` and another four in a different color for `Group 2`.

Comment: Thanks Auggie, that provides two boxplots side by side but I am hoping to have both scatter, and box plots side by side. So in the pic attached previously, there would essentially be 8 'sets' of scatter and box plots

Comment: In the same plot?

Comment: If possible. So it would have cat 1, group 1 vs group 2; cat2, group 1 vs group 2 etc